# Save Menu Item is not enableing when using ISaveablePart2 in SWT

Tags: java, swt

Below call which implements ViewPart  on which I am performing drag and drop

```
public class DiagramWindow extends ViewPart implements ISaveablePart2 {

    private boolean isDirty;
    private boolean saveNeeded;

    public void setDirty(boolean isDirty, boolean saveNeeded) {
        this.isDirty = isDirty;
        this.saveNeeded = saveNeeded;
        firePropertyChange(PROP_DIRTY);
    }
}
```

For menu item, I register it in class which extents ActionBarAdvisor:

```
saveFileAction = ActionFactory.SAVE.create(window);
register(saveFileAction);
```

The code part where I call

```
@Override
public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
    //DiagramWindow view
    view.setDirty(true, true);
}
```

Comment: What is in the `isDirty` method?

Comment: Also note that the Save menu will only be enabled when your view is the active part (click on the part to make it active).

Answer (score 0):

greg-449 is right. What is in `isDirty` method? You should override isDirty method in your class `DiagramWindow`. By default it is false as far as I know. I think all you have to do is -

```
public boolean isDirty() 
{ 
   return this.isDirty; 
}
```